# Reason and solution for error -"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent "?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, libevent

While compiling my program which is using libevent library I am using gcc option -levent. But I am getting this error -

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent

I do not have libevent on my system so I am statically linking to it while compiling using

```
gcc -o Hello -static -I libevent-1.4.12-stable/ hello.c -levent
```

How can i resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where is the `libevent.(a|so)` file on your system?

If it isn't on your system's library path then you will have to add a `-L` option adding its location to the list of paths searched by the linker for libraries.

e.g.

```
gcc -L/folder/containing/event/lib -levent mysource.cc
```

Comment: I dont have libevent.(a|so).  I am statically including libevent using  gcc -o Hello -static -I libevent-1.4.12-stable/ hello.c -levent

Comment: If you want to link against the library (statically or dynamically) you *need* the library. The static library should be called libevent.a. If that is in libevent-1.4.12-stable, then you should provide `-Llibevent-1.4.12-stable` to tell the linker to look there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `libevent` on your system or need to specify its path explicitly (if its a third-party library you got with the headers).

I suspect its not in your default /lib paths.