# I'm having trouble using make

Tags: ubuntu, lib

hi I'm having trouble with "/ usr / bin / ld: cannot find -lras". I will be glad if you help me. thanks in advance

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lras
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: We probably need to see what's in the Makefile as well.  Can you edit the question and put that info in as well?

Comment: If you have specified a library with `-l` then the library is not where the compiler thinks it should be.  The directory needs to be specified with `-L` before the `-l`  and both of those must be after all the other filenames and options that you give the compiler.  So it would look like `g++ -options filenames -L/path/to/library -lras`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329638/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721283/reason-and-solution-for-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-levent